# Difference in using an LED with gpiozero vs. RPi.GPIO

Tags: pi-3, python, led, raspbian-stretch, gpiozero

I'm trying to turn on an LED and it was trivial with the `gpiozero` library. The following works just as expected.

```
# Version 1 (working)
import gpiozero
import time

led = gpiozero.LED(21)
led.on()
time.sleep(20)
led.off()
```

However, when I tried to switch over to `RPi.GPIO`, I can't get the same pin to go High.

```
# Version 2 (not working)
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD) # Use board pin-out instead of Broadcom
GPIO.setup(21, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(21, GPIO.HIGH)
time.sleep(20)
GPIO.output(21, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.cleanup()
```

When I execute Version 2 above and use a multimeter, I see that Pin 21 is approximately 0 V, when I expect it to be High. There are no errors printed. Did I port the code over correctly to use `RPi.GPIO`?

Pi 3 Model B running Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gpiozero module always uses Broadcom GPIO numbering to identify a GPIO.

The RPi.GPIO module can use physical pin numbering (BOARD) or Broadcom GPIO numbering (BCM).  The physical pin 21 is connected to GPIO 9.

See https://pinout.xyz/

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation. Using the `BCM` mode in my Version 2 code above got it running.